Update a database table, to remove duplicates, with data from another table
Consider the following two tables. Val1, Val2, and Val3 are combined to make a unique code. These are then tied to "Items" from another table (not depicted here, but only referenced by ItemId). Finally, another table has references to both the Table1 unique codes as well as the ItemIds.
Table1



ID
ItemId
Val1
Val2
Val3




1
2
aaa
bbb
100


2
2
aaa
bbb
100


3
2
ccc
ddd
222


4
2
ccc
ddd
222


5
3
ggg
hhh
100



Table2



ID
ItemId
Table1.Id




100
2
1


101
2
2


102
2
3


103
2
4



What happened is that duplicates were inserted into Table1 via an automated import process. I have since updated the import process to no longer insert duplicates, but I need to clean up the existing data.
I have a query to remove the duplicate values in Table1, but I cannot simply run it, because of the foreign key relation on Table2.
So, what I need to do is update the Table1.Id column in Table2 with the correct ID from Table1 and then I can separately run the query to remove the duplicates (from Table1).
I have something like the following:
update Table2
set Table1.Id = (
    select ID
    from Table1
    where ID in (
        select max(ID)  
        from Table1
        group by ItemId, Va1, Val2, Val3
        having count(*) > 1
    )
    --and ItemId = 2  --added for testing
)
where Table1.ID in (
    select id
    from Table1
    where id not in (
        select max(id)
        from Table1
        group by ItemId, Va1, Val2, Val3
    )
    --and ItemId = 2  --added for testing
)

So, effectively, I want row 100 in Table2 to have Table1.Id set to 2, and row 102 to have Table1.Id set to 4.
Then rows 1 and 3 in Table1 will no longer be referenced in Table2 and can thus be deleted.
As you can see, I can do this for the trivial (or specific) example. However, I am struggling to genericize it so that it will handle multiple ids and all cases. Note: ultimately there will be 1000s of updates happening.
I can loop through a result set, I just really wanted a clever way do this in a single Update statement.

How do you know that row 100 maps to 2 and not 4?

va1 corrected to val1. Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/71HPcLBA

Why not just use ON DELETE CASCADE in the foreign key? (Then when you delete the duplicates from Table1, the associated rows in Table2 will also get deleted.)

How about using the min over partition by as your CTE for an update.
Here is the fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/RKUjhvB1
  WITH MinIDCTE AS (
        SELECT ID,
               ItemId,
               Val1,
               Val2,
               MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId, Val1, Val2) AS MinID
        FROM Table1
    )
    UPDATE t2
    SET t2.Table1_Id = m.MinID
    FROM Table2 t2
    JOIN MinIDCTE m ON t2.Table1_Id = m.ID;


The Op's description would be MAX(id) of the duplicates.

You could use a temp table to perform the grouping once to detect which IDs to update and delete.
SELECT MIN(ID) as [Duplicate ID to remove] , MAX(ID) as [ID to change to] 
INTO #TEMP
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ItemId, Val1, Val2, Val3
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;

SELECT * FROM #TEMP;

UPDATE  Table2
SET Table1Id=[ID to change to]  
FROM #TEMP 
WHERE Table1Id=[Duplicate ID to remove];
  
DELETE 
FROM Table1 
WHERE   Table1.ID in 
(  
 SELECT [Duplicate ID to remove] FROM #TEMP 
)
  
SELECT * FROM Table1;
SELECT * FROM Table2;

DROP TABLE #TEMP;

fiddle
Table1



ID
ItemId
Val1
Val2
Val3




2
2
aaa
bbb
100


4
2
ccc
ddd
222


5
3
ggg
hhh
100



Table 2



ID
ItemId
Table1Id




100
2
2


101
2
2


102
2
4


103
2
4




What happens if there are 3 duplicates?

Here's a solution that might work for you:
SELECT  *
INTO #table1
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, 2, N'aaa', N'bbb', 100)
    ,   (2, 2, N'aaa', N'bbb', 100)
    ,   (3, 2, N'ccc', N'ddd', 222)
    ,   (4, 2, N'ccc', N'ddd', 222)
    ,   (5, 3, N'ggg', N'hhh', 100)
    ,   (6, 2, N'aaa', N'bbb', 100)
    ,   (7, 2, N'aaa', N'bbb', 100)
) t (ID,ItemId,Val1,Val2,Val3)

SELECT  *
INTO #table2
FROM    (
        VALUES  (100, 2, 1)
        ,   (101, 2, 2)
        ,   (102, 2, 3)
        ,   (103, 2, 4)
        ,   (104, 2, 6)
        ,   (104, 2, 7)
    ) t2 (ID,ItemId,[Table1.Id])

UPDATE  t2
SET [Table1.Id] = maxID
FROM    (
    SELECT  MAX(t1.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.Val1, t1.Val2, t1.Val3) maxID
    ,   t2.*
    FROM    #table1 t1
    INNER JOIN #table2 t2
        ON  t2.[Table1.Id] = t1.ID
    ) t2
WHERE   t2.[Table1.Id] <> t2.maxID

-- Delete duplicates
DELETE  t
FROM    (
    SELECT  MAX(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Val1, Val2, Val3) AS maxID
    ,   ID
    FROM    #table1 t
) t
WHERE   ID <> maxID

I added some more sample rows to get a better test.

First, you update table2 so all duplicate rows get the maximum ID, per your Val1,Val2,Val3 grouping.

Then i delete the duplicates from the table 1. You can perhaps add some belts and suspenders so you only delete those from table 1 without a record in table 2 as well.


